# How to lookup data from a csv file

Tags: arrays, bash, lookup

I have an array and a csv file. I'm trying to get data from the csv file that match with the data from the array.

Here's my array:

```
array[12345678876543]=ID00000111
array[87654321234567]=ID00000222
```

and here is the data from csv file:

```
12345678876543,floor1
87654321234567,floor2
```

Im trying to get this output:

```
ID00000111 floor1
ID00000222 floor2
```

I tried this sytax but I can only get the floor number.

```
for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    awk -F, -v serial="${key}" '$1 == serial { print $2; exit}' test.csv
done
```

I hope someone could help me in my problem.

Comment: How are you putting values into the array?

Comment: I grep data from a file and make associative array from the grep output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the first entry in your csv file is the `key` to the array.

```
#!/bin/bash

array[12345678876543]=ID00000111
array[87654321234567]=ID00000222

while read -r line; do

    key=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)
    val=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2-)

    echo ${array[$key]} $val

done < test.csv
```

You can also do something like this which would be closer to what you have right now:

```
for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    echo ${array[$key]} $(grep "$key" test.csv | cut -d, -f2-)
done
```